# How to decode token ids into words?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-hub

The [text preprocessing](https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_preprocess/3) models on the hub describe how to convert an input sentence, like "I am a boy", into token ids. But it does not show me how to convert those token ids back into words. I also checked the [transformer-encoders](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/common_saved_model_apis/text#transformer-encoders) document, but I still cannot find any clue.

I did find a [detokenize](https://www.tensorflow.org/text/guide/tokenizers#detokenization) example, but I could not figure out if the token ids used in `tf-text` are the same as the ids used in the `bert_en_uncased_preprocess` models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use `assets/vocab.txt` file in the [model](https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_preprocess/3) directory. The line numbers in the file should correspond to token ids.